# babel output filename option

Tags: gulp, babeljs

What is the [babel option](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/options/) to rename output transpiled file.

With babel-cli it is `-o`

```
babel script.js -o script.transpiled.js
```

Is there a corresponding babel option that can be used with [gulp-babel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-babel) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As filename is handled for you by gulp-babel, you might want to use `gulp-rename` as an additional pipe

```
var rename = require('gulp-rename');

gulp.task('default', () =>
    gulp.src('script.js')
        .pipe(babel({
            presets: ['@babel/env']
        }))
        .pipe(rename(function(path) {
          path.basename = 'script.transpiled';
          path.extname = '.js';
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
);
```